# error 404 during use web service Java - angular

Tags: java, javascript, json, angularjs

When I send obiect from angular to java controller using JSON in firebug's controller shows me error 404. It means that angular can't find this path, but backend in java receive this message. Problem is because I can't response message to angular.

this is json:

```
{"title":"sdtgb","authors":[{"author_id":60,"author":"Brandon Sanderson"}],"genres":[{"genre_id":14,"genre":"Satyra"}],"description":"sdtb","path_image":"19674.png"}
```

java controller:

```
@SuppressWarnings("finally")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/rest/book", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public MessageDTO addNewBook(@RequestBody BookDTO newBook) {
        MessageDTO message = new MessageDTO();
        try {
            bookService.addNewBook(newBook);
            message.setCheck(true);
        } catch (BookTitleException e) {
            message.setCheck(false);
            message.setDescription("Ksiązka o tym tytule juz istnieje.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
            return message;
        }
    }
```

And this is path when angular sending message and error from firebug:

**`"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/engineering-project-web/rest/book"`**

BookDTO:

```
public class BookDTO implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5057364006691079475L;

    private AuthorEntity [] authors;    
    private String description; 
    private GenreEntity [] genres;  
    private String title;
    private String path_image;

    /* getters and setters */
}
```

**Java Script:**

Controller:

```
var book = {
            title : $scope.title,
            authors : $scope.author,
            genres : $scope.genre,
            description : $scope.description,
            path_image: null
        }

NewBookFct.addNewBook(book)
                .then( function(resolve){
                    if(resolve.check){
                        alert("Ksiazka została dodana.");
                    }else{
                        alert(resolve.description);
                    }
                }, function(reason){
                    console.log(reason);
                });
```

Service:

```
service.addNewBook = function(book){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        bookResource.save(book)
            .$promise.then( function(data){
                deferred.resolve( data );
            }, function(){
                deferred.reject("Error during adding new book.");
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your js codes ?

Comment: I find that Chrome + [Postman extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) are really great for debugging HTTP.

Comment: Yes I can. I put JS codes.

Answer (score 0):

Problably you are running your Angular application from localhost:3000 or other port, and the Java Web from localhost:8080. That means you need to make a "cross-site" request, which is something usually blocked for security purposes.

You need to configure CORS on your web app. This can easily be done by adding a library and configuring your web.xml. Read more here: http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter.html

If you are using maven, just add this dependecy:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Then add something like this to your web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET, POST, HEAD, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

In the configurations above I'm enabling CORS to GET, POST, HEAD, PUT, DELETE and OPTIONS requests to any URL under the /api path within my web appliction.